# In a should bool clause in elasticsearch what is default score mode?

Tags: elasticsearch

Actually i am writing three query inside my should boo query clause in ES now i was wondering what is the default score_mode of the should clause as i want to use maximum of all three query score how can i achieve that. My query is given below now where to define score_mode ??

```
bool: {
                "disable_coord": true,
                "should": [
                  {
                    term : { 'address.area2' : search_area2 }
                  },
                  {
                    term : { "address.area1" : search_area1 }
                  },
                  {
                    term : { 'address.city' : search_city }
                  }
                ], "boost": 2.0
              }
```

Answer (score 4):

From the [Bool Query docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html):

> The bool query takes a more-matches-is-better approach, so the score
>   from each matching must or should clause will be added together to
>   provide the final _score for each document.

To override that behavior, wrap your `bool` in a

[Function Score Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/query-dsl-function-score-query.html). You can define a [Field Value Factor Function](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-field-value-factor)  for `address.area2`, one for `address.area1` and one for `address.city`, then use `max` as `score_mode`.

The resulting function score should be something like the following (did not try, you may have to modify a bit)

```
"function_score": {
    "query": YOUR_BOOL_QUERY,
    "boost": 2,
    "functions": [
        {
            "field_value_factor": {
                "field": "address.area2",
                "factor": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "field_value_factor": {
                "field": "address.area1",
                "factor": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "field_value_factor": {
                "field": "address.city",
                "factor": 1
            }
        }
    ],
    "score_mode": "max",
    "boost_mode": "replace"
}
```

**UPDATE:**

added `"boost_mode": "replace"` according to [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/query-dsl-function-score-query.html), because we want to ignore the query score and only use our function score

Comment: tell me one thing suppose i am trying to search a string "noun" which is present in field a and field b now in first case if i will search only in field a and second case i will search in both fields a and b now my question is, is scoring equal now for both cases or in first case as "noun" is present in two fields it will be more, actually i want it to be same for my work that's why asking ??

Comment: @amanverma Maybe `"boost_mode": "replace"` was missing, I'm updating the answer